# "Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'T' ('[String : String]' vs. '[String]')"

Tags: swift

I have the following piece of code which gives error "Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'T' ('[String : String]' vs. '[String]')"

```
request.sendRequest(toUrlPath: "https://google.ca", selection: 1, completion:
                            { (result: [String], cookies: [String : String]) in
```

YET here is the function sendRequest

```
func sendRequest<T:Decodable>(toUrlPath urlPath: String, selection: Int, completion: @escaping (T, T)->Void)
```

& in the function sendRequest, I either do completion as

```
completion(results!, "" as! T)
```

OR

```
let sortableHeaders = r.allHeaderFields as! [String: String]
            completion(results!, sortableHeaders as! T)
```

Why am I experiencing this error?

Comment: The issue here is that you have only one generic type in your method. If you need two try `func sendRequest<T: Decodable, U: Decodable>(toUrlPath urlPath: String, selection: Int, completion: @escaping (T, U)->Void)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing this error becuase in `sendRequest`'s signature:

```swift
func sendRequest<T:Decodable>(toUrlPath urlPath: String, selection: Int, completion: @escaping (T, T)->Void)
```

in `completion: @escaping (T, T) -> Void`, you've specified that the completion would take in two arguments, both of type `T` but **not different types even if they both conform to `Decodable`** (that's what `(T, T)` means).

When you call `sendRequest`, in `result: [String]`, you implicitly specified that `T` for `sendRequest` is `[String]`, which leads the compiler to think that the second argument should be `[String]` (`T`) as well. However, in your call, you expected a `[String : String]` for the second argument, thus the compiler gave you the error.

---

If the types for your completion is fixed, you don't need generics here. 
Change `sendRequest` to be

```swift
func sendRequest(toUrlPath urlPath: String, selection: Int, completion: @escaping ([String], [String : String])->Void)
```

Comment: So how would I fix this so its [String], [String : String]

Comment: @Bob Is the type of `results` always `[String]`?

Comment: I guess I can't have differen't types in a tuple, must be same?

Comment: @Bob `([String], [String : String])` in your completion handler is not a tuple. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that